# Images generated by a button are not loading on first click

Tags: javascript, html, image, button

I am attempting to make a page where you can use buttons to switch between images on a canvas. The images (real time stream data) do not appear on the first click of the button but after clicking around on them or other buttons, will all appear eventually. The images are all very small, and I have tried using an context.onload command but that doenst help.

www.cooswatershed.org/streamdata

Here is how I am drawing them in:

```
<button id="clickme" onclick="changewfk()">West Fork Millicoma</button><br /><br />


<canvas id="myCanvas" width="700" height="504"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">

var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var contxt = canvas.getContext('2d');
var imageObja = new Image();

function changewfk(){
    imageObja.src = "/Gaging_Data/WFK_Gage_Screen.jpeg";
    contxt.clearRect ( 0 , 0 , canvas.width, canvas.height );
    contxt.drawImage(imageObja, 0, 0, 700, 504);
    alloff();
    mapfunct = false;

  }
```

Comment: Where are you defining your other variables? (imageObja, contxt, canvas)

Comment: They are defined in the same script with the changewfk() after the canvas is created